# dynamically create form and store it on database

Tags: dynamic

I am working on a survey website for my thesis. As a requirement of my system i need to provide my users the ability to create their own form (like if the want to add a question with radio buttons to place the choices of answers or just a question with a textbox) also, i need to store how my users designed the survey that was created. I tried searching on the internet and hasnt found any realiable source of forum for my problem. So i tried asking here to look for even a good tutorial links or forums that you guys may know that can help me.

Comment: you will not get any help from this forum unless show us your effort. Check the rules: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try https://kahoot.com/

If you you need to create your own, you'll need to get a grasp of php and mysql, which is probably quicker to learn